# Code generation whit NSwag for a project written in French: Bad client name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nswag

I am working on a project written in French.
The classes are named in French.
I want to use code generation for a C# client.

```
[Route("[controller]s")]
public class EtablissementControleur : ControllerBase
{
  ...
}
```

My api route is good and my swagger documentation is good, because I took care of the translation.

/api/v1/etablissements/{id}/adresse

Here is the partial configuration of the generator

nswag.json

```
  "codeGenerators": {
    "openApiToCSharpClient": {
      "className": "{controller}HttpService",
...
```

The name of the generated service is EtablissementControleurHttpService, whereas I was expecting EtablissementHttpService.

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag", "13.18.0.0 (NJsonSchema v10.8.0.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0))")]
    public partial class EtablissementControleurHttpService : IEtablissementControleurHttpService
    {
```

Should I tell the generator to remove the word Controller?
Or should I modify the swagger documentation to support it?
Thanks for your help

Comment: If the class name is `EtablissementControleur` then why would you not expect `EtablissementControleurHttpService`?. Your `nswag.json` says `"className": "{controller}HttpService"` and the `{controller}` is `EtablissementControleur`, right?

Comment: Does it really make sense to translate the word Controller into French? I would just name the class EtablissementController - the first part I can understand the reason for translating, but `Controller` is almost like a keyword in the context of web api...